# Kivy Python list, и DropDown

Tags: python, list, kivy

ребят помогите не могу понять, где косяк. Вот кусок Кода.
1.Я получаю данные с файла, split методом убираю пробелы и методом append добавляю в list_wes.
Далее я его разпарсиваю и помещаю в другой список ip_list. Все работает я проверял, вывод верный через print. Показывает Данные. Но почему то когда я создаю кнопки, а мне надо для каждого елемента создать ее, они не создаюся.!!!
Но если в ip_list указать явно елементы например:

```
ip_list=['192.168.0.1','192.168.0.10','192.168.0.14]
```

то все в норме, кнопки без проблем создаются.
Почему не создаются кнопки хотя данные в списке имеются ??

```
list_wes = []
ip_list = []
def parser():
    cmd='ip dhcp-server lease print detail'
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    BOOK = stdout.readlines()
    res =''.join(BOOK)
    text = res.split()
    for i in text:
        list_wes.append(i)
    for x in list_wes:
        if x[0:8] == 'address=':
            ip_list.append(x[8:])
    print(ip_list)
#вывод списка 
['172.20.26.5', '172.20.26.6', '172.20.26.16', '172.20.26.17', '172.20.26.18', '172.20.26.20', '172.20.26.21', '172.20.26.32']
class Workscreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Workscreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        start = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(0.4, 0.3), padding=8,
                          pos_hint={'top': 0.9, 'center_x': 0.5})
        drop_down = Button(text=str('Выберите Точку'), size_hint_y=None, height=70, on_press=self.drop)
        start.add_widget(drop_down)
        self.dropdown = DropDown(auto_dismiss=False)
        listas = ip_list
        for i in listas:
            btn = Button(text=i, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)
        self.add_widget(start)
    def drop(self, drop_down):
        self.dropdown.open(drop_down)
```

Comment: распечатайте получившийся в коде и лист и посмотрите на него. чего гадать?

Comment: В том то и дело я пробовал, создал кнопку которая печатает лист именно с класса, Workscreen. И все печатается корректно, но в dropdown не добавляются

Comment: еще заметил что, если допустим прописать в Button(text=ip_list[0]) иначе говоря указать 0 интекдс, то бьет ошибку out of range, что говорит мол список пуст. Но почему он пуст если я до этого экрана уже поместил туда значения. ?